# How to include reactivex dependency in Cloud Code

Tags: parse-platform, rxjs

I would like to use a 3rd party library in my cloude code. It is located here https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS

I have downloaded the .js file and put it in my cloud/ directory and tried to import it using

```
var rxModule = require('cloud/rx.js');
```

I have had success with other libraries but for this one it just throws

```
Uncaught Error: This operation is not supported
```

when i call parse deploy

Is there another way I can include a 3rd party lib?

Answer (score 0):

RX can be installed using NPM:

```
$ npm install rx
```

It can then be used as follows:

```
var rxModule = require('rx');
```

There are great instructions and samples at https://www.npmjs.com/package/rx

Answer (score 0):

@Darussian, I do not know if this is still relevant but I wanted to the same thing.

From what I understand, Rx won't work in Parse Cloud Code because `setTimeout()` and `setInterval()` are not defined, and they are needed for Rx.Schedulers to work.

So, what I ended up doing was trying with other similar libraries. The one I got to work was [Kefir.JS](http://rpominov.github.io/kefir/). It works similar to Rx and has some of the same methods. You may be disconcerted at first but should be able to transfer any Rx code you wanted to build to Kefir.

One thing that helped me a lot was using `scan()` combined with `last()` to emulate Rx `reduce()` method (which is not on Kefir by default).